# Is there any Systems Manager like service in Azure for SSH tunneling to access to database via local machine?

Tags: database, azure, aws-ssm

AWS has a service named AWS Systems Manager that we can use SSH tunnel through it to access to private resources in VPC. Which makes it very easy to get access to RDS database using it from local whithout worring about SSH credentials.

Recenly I'm working on Azure and need to make a tunneling to private database from local machine. I am wondering if there is any similar service in Azure that can help with this issue?

Comment: What type of database it is ? is an azure sql db or deployed to vm ?

Comment: @Thomas It is Azure PSQL DB

Comment: Can you add firewall rules to connect to your db ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-firewall-rules
You could otherwise use private link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-data-access-and-security-private-link

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the message. I don't want to make prod database public available, so the firewall rules would not help in this case. The database has private link and private DNS, and I added a  vm bastion-host for SSH connection to database which has private DNS/IP. However the problem is that, someone should take care of VM-bastionhost maintenance. also each developer who wants to get access to db , need to add public-key to bastionhost which is not convenient way. I was wondering if there is any managed service like AWS System Manager that can help ?